# Perform the action when the key is pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on my project and i need to add an action that is only performed while left CTRL is pressed

This is my code:

```
   private void Izrada_kartice_KeyDown(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if(e.Control)
        {
            promijeni_veličinu_naslov = true;

            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

    }

    private void Izrada_kartice_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control)
        {
            promijeni_veličinu_naslov = false;

            this.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
```

Now when I run this code and press CTRL all is OK, but when I release CTRL 
 nothing happened.

I was try this:

```
     private void Izrada_kartice_KeyDown(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        promijeni_veličinu_naslov = true;

        this.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

}

private void Izrada_kartice_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        promijeni_veličinu_naslov = false;

        this.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

This works fine but I need do this with CTRL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your second code, replace Keys.A with Keys.ControlKey like this:

```
private void Izrada_kartice_KeyDown(object 
sender,KeyEventArgs e)
{

if(e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
{
    promijeni_veličinu_naslov = true;

    this.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

}

private void Izrada_kartice_KeyUp(object sender, 
KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
{
    promijeni_veličinu_naslov = false;

    this.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The KeyUp event will fire when you release Ctrl, but the `e.Control` boolean is not set to True because Ctrl is no longer being held down.

In short: Don't detect the release of Ctrl by inspecting `e.Control`, inspect the `e.KeyCode` instead; it will be `Keys.ControlKey`

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
{
    ...
}
```